# Reprompting user when negative float value input

Tags: c, cs50

so I'm a complete newb to C and I'm struggling with the language. I need to write a program that will re-prompt a user to input a number if they input a negative number untill they produce a positive one. I have the below so far, no error messages are showing but when I type in a negative float value it does not re-prompt me, it just displays the number. Any ideas?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float get_positive_float(string prompt);

int main(void)
{
    float f = get_float("Cash: ");
    printf("%f\n", f);
}

float get_positive_float(string prompt)
{
    float n;
    do {
        n = get_float("%s", prompt);
    } while (n < 0);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: This code is hard to understand. The only code that checks for a value being negative is inside `get_positive_int()`, but you talk about floats, and that function is never called. Please don't include random things in questions, it makes it much harder to understand. Also, where is `get_float()`?

Comment: you should start by writing a `get_float` function as that's missing from your code

Comment: Consider validating by accepting a string as the input and then parse it.

Comment: . o O ( cs50.h should be deleted from the internet )

Comment: I believe the get_float is defined in the cs50.h. At least the float part seems to be working since I get a return valve with multiple decimal places. I just don't understand what's wrong with the second half. I've tried using 'float' instead of 'int' in the second half but still nothing happens.

Comment: What should happen? You never call `get_positive_int()`.

Comment: I've updated the second half of my code. I'm confused because I fee like I do call that on line 18

Comment: No, you don't call `get_positive_float()` anywhere. In `main()` you call `get_float()`.

Comment: `float f = get_float("Cash: ");` ==> `float f = get_positive_float("Cash: ");`

Comment: Got it! Thanks. I had to put "get_positive_float" in the main thing and not just "get float". Thanks again.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Look again.

Answer (score 0):

```
float get_positive_float(char const *prompt)
{
    float result;
    while (prompt && printf(prompt), scanf(" %f", &result) != 1 || result < 0.f) {
        fputs("Please only enter positive values!\n\n", stderr);
        for (int ch; (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF;);  // clear the rest of the line
    }
    return result;
}
```

A version using the thingies from `<cs50.h>` might look like that:

```
float get_positive_float(string prompt)
{
    float result;
    while ((result = get_float(prompt)), result < 0.f) {
        fputs("Please only enter positive values!\n\n", stderr);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The problem though is, that floating point numbers aren't suitable for amounts of money. Use an integer type and calculate in cents. For output divide by 100.

Comment: For whatever reason the problem I'm working on needs to be done as a float. I just need it to re-prompt the user when they enter a negative value. It worked fine when I did the exact same thing but with integers. I've updated the 2nd half of my code to refer to float and not int. But still no joy:

Comment: See my comment beneath your question. For how to do it using standard-C without depending on cs50.h see my answer.